# What wires to connect ceiling fan bypassing remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm putting in a ceiling fan with no lights attached. My new fan has a receiver and remote but my husband pulled wires out of the receiver.  The room is wired for a wall switch to control the ceiling fan. I read where I can bypass the remote but the wires coming out of fan are red ,grey, and pink. In my ceiling are red, black. White, and the ground. Assuming red to red. What color goes with the grey and what color goes with the pink?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the wiring diagram that came with the fan and a picture of the ceiling box?

Comment: Just for better understanding, why did he pull (cut) the wires

Answer (score -4):

Without a wiring diagram it's just an educated guess. If the fan came stock with no light option, grey off the fan is likely neutral. You would ground the metal bracket the fan is on it should have a ground jumper from the fan to the bracket. The red/black in your ceiling are probably separate power hots to power the lights and fan independently but it is possible you have a 3 way configuration. Do you have switches on opposite sides of the room that operate the fan? I'm assuming not. Now it's a 50/50 shot of what's hot.... I'm betting the pink is the fan power and the red was a supply line into the remote module.... I'd try white to gray, black to pink cap off your red if there are no lights and try it, if we guessed wrong you could send line voltage in reverse back to the fan body, so be careful when you turn the breaker back on and flip the switch. You might see if the manufacturer has a wiring diagram before you proceed.

Comment: Guessing is a VERY BAD idea.   Depending upon the country of manufacture, color wires can mean different things.   The OP needs a wiring diagram and/or detailed installation instructions to be safe.  Sorry for the DV, but this is bad advice.